# Loading individual css files for custom modules

Tags: theming

I have a custom module that creates three pages. Each page has a controller, twig file, and css file. What I'd like to do is only load the css files when they are needed. I created a libraries.yml file like this:

```
mymodule:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/page1.css: {}
      css/page2.css: {}
      css/page3.css: {}
```

This loads the three css files whenever I display any of the three files. What I'd like to do is somehow load page1.css only when page1 is requested. Is there a way to subdivide the libraries.yml file into sections that each specified one css file, then load it into the template with an `attach_library()` call or preprocessing??

Or do I need to create a separate module for each page? The reason I put the three pages in one module is they are a section of the site that share other assets.

Comment: As an aside - it’s a good idea to only use `version` if you intend to increment it with every change to your library. That version number forms the cache buster string for those specific js/css assets, and can cause problems if you’re using a reverse proxy like varnish otherwise. I’d you remove `version`, the global cache buster string will be used, which changes with cache clears, and sidesteps the issue.

Answer (score 7):

You can create multiple library entries in *.libraries.yml.

```
page.1:
  css:
    theme:
      css/page1.css: {}

page.2:
  css:
    theme:
      css/page2.css: {}

page.3:
  css:
    theme:
      css/page3.css: {}
```

Then you can attach the relevant library to the node it should be attached to using `my_module.page.3` (for page three). You would do attach it to the render array being returned from your controller on the given page as follows:

```
class ExampleController extends ControllerBase {
  function firstPageCallback() {
    // Build your $page array (not shown).
    // Then attach:
    $page['#attached']['libraries'][] = 'my_module.page.1';
  }
}
```